# Is there any benchmarks for keyword extraction?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, benchmarking, keyword, extract

I will do keyword extraction from documents. But I can't how to evaluate the accuracy(or precision, recall), because I don't know about ground truths of data.
I want to do evaluate the accuracy(or precision, recall) for my model. Is there any benchmarks?

Comment: What do you mean by keyword extraction? Do you mean extracting the most important words within the sentence just like [this image](https://pcdn.piiojs.com/i/kqctmw/vw,730,vh,0,r,0,pr,1,wp,1/https%3A%2F%2Fmonkeylearn.com%2Fstatic%2Fimg%2Fkeyword-extraction%2Fproduct-review-example.png)

Comment: I have seen papers (e.g. TextRank) where they create ground-truth data using human annotators. So these datasets might be available to download.

Comment: There is some the Inspec database which was used in TextRank paper. Did you find any benchmark dataset?

Answer (score 0):

For a high-quality "keyword extraction" you do not necessarily need a "ground truth". There are also algorithms, which work without a ground truth. Here is a comparison of different algorithms and their performance
https://monkeylearn.com/blog/keyword-extraction-tools/